# How to trigger google function from stackdriver logs, similar to how we do in AWS with cloudwatch events triggering lambda?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to trigger a google cloud function from stackdriver log, say if my VM goes down I need to perform some operation using function. Similar to how we do in AWS with cloudwatch events triggering lambda.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to directly invoke a function from a log, but you can piece it together in two parts:

1. Export the logs you care about to Cloud Pub/Sub

   https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/
2. Subscribe a Cloud Function to the topic

   https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub
   and https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [configure StackDriver to call a webhook](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks), which you then implement as a [HTTP-triggered Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http).